# Shortcut for selecting previous or next item in outline panel

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to customize a shortcut for selecting the previous or next item when the outline panel is focused instead of using down-arrow and up-arrow.

It seems like there is not an outline panel specific command for achieving this, but I haven't been able to find the correct one if it even exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the outline view is active, this should work, in your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+d",              // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "list.focusDown",
  "when": "outline.active && !editorTextFocus"
},
{
  "key": "alt+u",              // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "list.focusUp",
  "when": "outline.active && !editorTextFocus"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I had to add `&& !editorTextFocus` for some reason because `outline.active` seems to be true when editor/explorer is focused.

Comment: Good catch - I'll add it to the answer for clarity.